# JQuery removed background from iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to remove the background image on a page that's being loaded via an iframe within a lightbox effect.  I have verified that body is the correct element within the iframe that's being selected, but I can't get the background image to go away.  Am I missing something obvious?

```
var body = jQuery('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('body');

body.css({
 'background': 'none',
 'background-image': 'none',
 'background-color': '#fff'
});
```

**UPDATE:** Currently my CSS for this element reads (according to firebug) ...

```
body {
   background-color:#5A7E92;
   background-image:url("/images/background.gif");
   border:10px solid #021E2F;
   font-family:verdana,san-serif;
   font-size:10pt;
   margin:auto;
}
```

**UPDATE:** You can see the example here by clicking the "Mail" link....
http://www.retailcustomerexperience.com/article/21532/GlobalShop-DOOH-measurement-essential-for-reaching-customers

Comment: Is the framed page on the same domain as the parent page?

Comment: Yes they're on the same domain.

Comment: Just to double check, are you sure you're calling this javascript after the iframe has been loaded?

Comment: Yes it is being called, console.log(body) confirms this.

Comment: I visited the link; your code is already working correctly.

Comment: Can't confirm. Opening the page you provide and clicking the email-image-link and checking with Firebug gives me `body { background-color:#5A7E92; ... }` so no background-image set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background is probably on some other element.

Inspect the page in the `<iframe>` in Firebug and check which element has a background.

Comment: Confirmed, it is on the body element.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you let the values be empty it won't actually do what you're expecting. Try setting background to 'inherit' and see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `background-image` to `none`. That is a valid value for that css property, and I believe that will explicitly remove your background image.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the complete answer, but this may help you find the answer.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="width:756px;height:439px;background-image:none;background-color:transparent" src="http://janemonheitonline.com/photos?KeepThis=true&amp;" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true"> </iframe>
```

The "allowtransparency" is required for Internet Explorer to remove the background image and background color on the iframe. Try this code so see if the background image is on the iframe rather than the body.

You can see how the code works at http://janemonheitonline.com 
by clicking on any of the main navigation links.